# FK constraint error on my booking postgresql database table that refers to more than one foreign key?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to sql databases, any help would be really appreciated.I keep getting the error messages for my tables below. It mentions about an issue with the fk constraint

```
TRUNCATE TABLE
ERROR:  insert or update on table "bookings" violates foreign key constraint "fk_space"
DETAIL:  Key (space_id)=(1) is not present in table "spaces".
ERROR:  insert or update on table "bookings" violates foreign key constraint "fk_space"
DETAIL:  Key (space_id)=(2) is not present in table "spaces".
NOTICE:  truncate cascades to table "bookings"
TRUNCATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
NOTICE:  truncate cascades to table "spaces"
NOTICE:  truncate cascades to table "bookings"
TRUNCATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
NOTICE:  truncate cascades to table "bookings"
TRUNCATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1



TRUNCATE TABLE bookings RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;
INSERT INTO bookings (space_id, host_id, user_id, start_date, end_date, confirmed) VALUES ('1', '1', '1', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-14', 'yes');
INSERT INTO bookings (space_id, host_id, user_id, start_date, end_date, confirmed) VALUES ('2', '2', '2', '2022-02-02', '2022-02-14', 'no');

TRUNCATE TABLE spaces RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;
INSERT INTO spaces (name, description, price, availability, host_id) VALUES ('property1','description1', 1, 'available', 1);
INSERT INTO spaces (name, description, price, availability, host_id) VALUES ('property2','description2', 12, 'not available', 2);

TRUNCATE TABLE hosts RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;
INSERT INTO hosts (name, password, email) VALUES ('host1', 'password1', 'host1@email.com');
INSERT INTO hosts (name, password, email) VALUES ('host2', 'password2', 'host2@email.com');
INSERT INTO hosts (name, password, email) VALUES ('host3', 'password3', 'host3@email.com');

TRUNCATE TABLE users RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;
INSERT INTO users (name, password, email) VALUES ('user1', 'password1', 'email1@email.com');
INSERT INTO users (name, password, email) VALUES ('user2', 'password2', 'email2@email.com');
INSERT INTO users (name, password, email) VALUES ('user3', 'password3', 'email3@email.com');
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? (update: `RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE` is for Posgres)

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I am using postgresql

Comment: This looks  like an out-of-order issue. I would normally truncate everything first, then  insert the data in order of need. `bookings` require a `space_id`, which suggests that you need to insert `spaces` first. It's the same issue with `hosts` and `users`. You have to fill the base tables first and then you  can  use those values in the other tables. There are also more complex ways to do this, such as ignoring checks/constraints on insert, etc.